# upload file with date using infopath form 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries, sharedpreferences, sharepoint-2013

Background: I want to make a form in SharePoint for the user to submit vendor information. In file attachment,they want to  Attach a document. whenever they attach a file, it automatically fill date at top of the document(Inside the document at top). When I use InfoPath's file attachment.I'm not sure that it's actually a SharePoint form instead of a standard form.